# Invalid file name error in eclipse for images

Tags: android

I'm facing the following error:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/Twitter.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

Twitter.png looks like a valid filename to me. None of the other images having names like Facebook.png, RSS.png work.

Help please!!

Comment: Its already showing that "must contain only [a-z0-9_.)" still you want  to go beyond the Android standards? if yes then its not possible.

Comment: "still you want to go beyond the Android standards"? He didn't know you couldn't use caps...

Comment: The full error should be: "Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])".  That is what Android Studio will tell you today.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

uppercase is not allowed for resource names..
only lowercase(a-z), 0-9, .(dot) and _ are valid.

Your image names should be `twitter.png`, `facebook.png`, `rss.png`

Comment: Worth noting that the filename cannot start with a number either. Bounced this around for about 45mins before finding this gold nugget...