# Corona always display a black screen in the build

Tags: coronasdk

I'm trying to make a build with Corona for Android devices.
Is a very simple app, only use a reference to de 'ui'

```
local ui = require("ui");


local btnright = ui.newButton{
    defaultSrc = "button-right.png",
    defaultX = 100,
    defaultY = 100,
    overSrc = "button-right-over.png",
    overX = 100,
    overY = 100,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
    id = "btn-right"
}
```

But, when I generate the apk, only display me a black screen and in the simulator shows me the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in android when naming the file or the image you must not use special character it must only contain `[a-z0-9_.]` and no capital letters too. you can see the widget button on corona simulator because simulator can read special character.
for more details about resource names refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730417/invalid-file-name-error-in-eclipse-for-images)
and change your widget name from:

```
local ui = require("ui");
local btnright = ui.newButton{
    defaultSrc = "button-right.png",
    defaultX = 100,
    defaultY = 100,
    overSrc = "button-right-over.png",
    overX = 100,
    overY = 100,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
    id = "btn-right"
}
```

to this

```
local ui = require("ui");   
local btnright = ui.newButton{
    defaultSrc = "button_right.png",
    defaultX = 100,
    defaultY = 100,
    overSrc = "button_right_over.png",
    overX = 100,
    overY = 100,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
    id = "btn-right"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of corona are you using?

Why not try the widget.newButton()?

check this out. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html

Answer (score 0):

Capital letters are allowed. I'm not sure about hyphens, but they are valid characters in Linux and Unix (the core OS used by Android and iOS)  However what is likely the cause is case sensitivity.  Devices like Android and iOS are case sensitive.  The simulator is not, so if you have a button named:

button-right.png

And the actual file name is:

Button-right.PNG

it won't match and it will generate an error.  You need to tether your device to your computer and view the device's console log. If you do not know how to do that please see this blog post:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I checked right now, but the problem was that corona does not include the ui.lua library in the apk package and was necessary include a lib chapeter before the build